# How to compare integer type and string type variable in Django using if template tag

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I am trying to compare two variables using if template tag. If condition is not working as **stock.id** is integer and **form.product_in_stock.value** is string.

```html
{% if form.product_in_stock.value == stock.id %}selected{% endif %}
```

Is there any way to type cast and then compare using if in django template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django templates, you cannot directly type-cast variables or use complex operations like type casting within the template language. However, you can achieve your goal by converting one of the variables to the same type as the other for the purpose of the comparison.

Assuming that `stock.id` is an integer and `form.product_in_stock.value` is a string, you can convert `stock.id` to a string for the comparison. Here's an example:

```
{% if form.product_in_stock.value == stock.id|stringformat:"d" %}
    selected
{% endif %}
```

In this example, `stock.id|stringformat:"d"` is used to convert the integer `stock.id` to a string before comparing it with `form.product_in_stock.value`.